# setting custom UIButton style according to its state

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I am creating a custom UIButton in my program (not in IB) and I would like it to show different images on different states, so I did :

```
UIImage *learnImg=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01" ofType:@"png"]];
self.learn=[[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
[self.learn setFrame:CGRectMake(148, 108,254,97)]; 
[[self.learn imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.learn setImage:learnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *learnSelected=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathForResource:@"02" ofType:@"png"]];
[self.learn setImage:learnSelected forState:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[self.learn addTarget:self action:@selector(loadLearn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The problem is, the two images have different sizes so when I click on the button, the position of the button got 'translated' (I believe this is due to the 'setFrame' behaviour since the xy location should be relative).

I couldn't think of a way to fix this, all I want is to make sure the button is right at the position during whatever states it's in. Is there anyway that I can set a complete set of style for each button state (frame, images etc)? Or any other thoughts?

Thank you!

*I finally worked this around by re-setting the center of the button through two action events: UIControlEventTouchDown and UIControlEventTouchCancel.
Thanks all for the comments.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIControlEventTouchDown` is not a state of the button. Its an event registered by the button. The various states for the `UIButton` are

```
enum {
    UIControlStateNormal       = 0,                       
    UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
    UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
    UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
    UIControlStateApplication  = 0x00FF0000,              // additional flags available for application use
    UIControlStateReserved     = 0xFF000000               // flags reserved for internal framework use
};
typedef NSUInteger UIControlState;
```

Comment: thanks but this is another problem i encountered. when i set the image under the state "UIControlStateHighlighted", the button never changes to the image i set, even when I also included the "UIControlStateSelected". No idea what's going on :S

Comment: Try changing the state of the button accordingly by using `button.selected = YES;` inside the button action and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Try setting the background image using `setBackgroundImage:forState:` this will stretch your image th fit the size. If you don't want this, experiment with the `imageEdgeInsets` property.

2.) The state you want for your "ontouch" image is UIControlStateHighlighted. If you want to do sth. custom with a "selected" state (`selected`property) you need to use combinations of the sates (`UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted` for selected+ontouch)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The size of the images has actually drawn perfectly on the button due to the "UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit" property, and it is also my intention that the button 'grows' bigger when the user clicks on it. Is there anyway I can fix one edge of the button to one position, and whenever it 'grows' it wont mess up the entire position?

Comment: try setting the `center` of the button and making it bigger by setting its bounds. if that is not sufficient you can mess with the layer's `anchorPoint`

Comment: thanks. I basically tried everything, nothing seems to be working. To be specific, the images are two cone-shaped geometries and they are transformed to fit into a designated space. The expected result is, when the user clicks the button, the 2nd larger cone kicks in overlapping the first one (their vertexes remain at the same position). It seems to be too difficult to implement by simply playing with frame/bounds etc. Guess the simplest way is to create the larger cone as an images and control its "hidden" property? >_<

Answer (score 0):

```
       UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [deleteButton setFrame:CGRectMake(285, 5, 30, 30)];
        deleteButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;     
        UIImage *newImage12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"];
        deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row;
        [deleteButton setImage:newImage12 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [deleteButton setImage:newImage12 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRemindersMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

give image name according to your button states.